# How to shift bibtex bibliography to the left?

Tags: bibtex

I'd like to shift all my bibliography to the left.   Am using bibtopic for multiple bibliographies.   Is there a way to set the left margin to shift all bib items leftwards?

Comment: @user11618617 Can you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) to your question?

Answer (score -2):

Its very hacky, but i got what i want by editing article.cls to change thebibliography environment,  changing 
           \leftmargin\labelwidth
to
           \leftmargin0pt

Comment: **Never change an original `*.cls` file!** You can patch it in your code or redefine used commands or environments.  If you show a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) in your question (as you should do usually here!) we can show you how to do the patching/redefining ...